# Какое sdk хорошо для освоения написания игр и приложений под виртуальную реальность?

Tags: c#, unity3d, 3d, sdk, vuforia

Мы пытались использовать Vuforia, но не разобрались, она хороша, как дополняшка к Unity и возможно всё-таки на нем и остановимся, но может что-то упускаем из вида?
Имеем знания в c# и 3д моделера хорошего уровня. Ничего не понимаем и ни разу не пробовали создавать виртуальную реальность.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо смотреть для чего собрались писать (смартфон или очки). Дополненная реальность или виртуальная реальность. Вообще советую использовать Vuforia, т.к. много уроков и материалов в интернете. Другие я не пробовал. Но есть например такие: [Oculus SDK](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/) или [Cardboard SDK](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity/).